# How to return htmlsafe string from typescript file in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to return `htmlsafe` string from component. is it possible? if so nay one help me?

here is my try:

ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  inputs = [{'name':'name1'},{'name':'name2'},{'name':'name3'}];

  getWrapped(input) {
    return `<div>${input.name}</div>`; //but not works!!
  }
}
```

template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let input of inputs">{{getWrapped(input)}}</li>
</ul>
```

I can do this in template itself. But still looking a solution from ts file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Angular **`Pipe`** for this as follows.

**TS**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })

@Injectable()
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(value) {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let input of inputs" [innerHTML]="getWrapped(input) | safeHtml"></li>
</ul>
```

**Find working [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57104777?file=src/app/app.component.ts).**

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  theHtmlString: string = '';
  name = 'Angular';
  inputs = [{ 'name': 'name1' }, { 'name': 'name2' }, { 'name': 'name3' }];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  getWrapped(input) {
    return this.theHtmlString = `<div>${input.name}</div>`;
  }

}
```

template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let input of inputs" [innerHTML]="theHtmlString">{{getWrapped(input)}}</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks everyone!!